# Determining rate of heat production across two wires of different materials

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, power

This a school-level based Physics question, but I'm not able to explain myself the answer.

> Question : Nickel and Copper wires having same shape, size are connected across a battery in turn. The rate of production of heat will be more in which wire ?

From this [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Resistivity_and_conductivity_of_various_materials) on Wikipedia, I got the following data.

Resistivity of copper $= 1.68\times 10^{−8}$

Resistivity of nickel $= 6.99\times 10^{−8}$

Now, $$P = V\times I = I^2\times R = \frac{V^2}{R}$$

I used the $I^2\times R$ formula and so the answer should be nickel. But what confused me is, why can't we use $V^2/R$ and say that the answer should be copper ?

Please clarify me which is the right answer and how.

(The word *in turn* is ambiguous to me. I don't understand if it means the wires are: connected alone and removed or connected one after another in series or connected over each other in parallel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the correct formula here to be use is $P=\displaystyle\frac{V^2}{R}$ because EMF (or potential difference if $r_{int}=0$) of the battery will remain constant. But the current in the circuit will depend on the resistance and will not be constant.

Comment: But how can we justify the fact that more resistance -> more friction among electrons -> more heat dissipated ?  Or am I missing something ? :)

Comment: Well, that's correct when two or more resistances are connected in series or more precisely, current should be constant.

Comment: Is there any general "trick" or fact to know which formula to use for questions like this ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on why the current won't be constant (in answer itself) ? Say I have two resistors of 5 ohm and 3 ohm resistance. So heat produced will be high in 3 ohm one ? :)

Comment: I've already explained. You just have to check whether $V$ or $I$ remains constant to use the formula from the two. In this case, we didn't change the battery so EMF is constant and $I,R$ are changing.